# Display 2D array from OpenCV in Matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, computer-vision

I have a setup in Python where I use the OpenCV library to read the frames of a video in as 2D arrays--these videos are grayscale, so I'm using unsigned 8-bit integers for the pixel values.

In my next step, I'm trying to use `pyplot.imshow()` from matplotlib to display the frame of the video. Unfortunately, I'm getting something that doesn't make any sense at all.

Here's the code to read the video:

```
import numpy as np
import cv

def read_video(filename):
  video = cv.CaptureFromFile('%s' % filename)
  num_frames = int(cv.GetCaptureProperty(video, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

  frames = []
  for i in range(0, num_frames):
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(video)
    if frame is None:
      quit('Failed to extract frame %s of %s!' % (i, num_frames))
    toadd = cv2numpy(frame, 'uint8')
    frames.append(np.array(toadd))
  return np.array(frames)
```

`cv2numpy` is a utility function that converts the OpenCV array to a numpy array (just a call to `fromstring` and then a `reshape`). Here's the code I'm using to plot the first frame of the video:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import matplotlib.cm as cm

frames = read_video('video.avi')
plot.imshow(frames[0], cmap = cm.gray)
plot.show()
```

In some other code, I used the OpenCV `SaveImage` on a single frame to provide a reference for what I would expect from `imshow`. [Here's the image I get from the former](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1377610/truth.png), and [here's the image I get from the code above](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1377610/actual.png).

As you can see they're wildly different. The only thing I can glean from the actual image is the striping: it looks almost like it's getting the dimensions wrong, that there are more pixels in the width than the height (this image is supposed to be 128 x 256). But I've tried transposing the array before plotting it, changing the `extent` and `aspect` and `shape` parameters as per the [imshow documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow), and with the exception of some bizarre pixel stretching I haven't found a fix.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT 1:** I figure it may be prudent to add the `cv2numpy` code, in case that reshaping is somehow muddling things (since my "truth" image above does not use that code and hence `cv2numpy` is involved only in the questionable pipeline).

```
def cv2numpy(cvarr, the_type):
  a = np.fromstring(
      cvarr.tostring(),
      dtype = the_type,
      count = cvarr.width * cvarr.height)
  a.shape = (cvarr.height, cvarr.width)
  return a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the problem is with your cv2numpy function. Try this one:

```
def cv2numpy(cvarr, the_type):
  a = np.asarray(cv.GetMat(cvarr), dtype=the_type)
  return a
```

It did the trick for me. If you aren't using a grayscale input (I know that you said you are using grayscale now) then you will need to convert using cv.CreateImage and cv.CvtColor.

Comment: This was exactly the issue. OpenCV was still reading the videos as RGB, so I added in the `cv.CreateImage` and `cv.CvtColor`, printed out the image, and it looks exactly like what I was expecting. Thanks so much! Apparently converting OpenCV arrays to numpy arrays via strings is suboptimal.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using version 2.3.1? Using **cv2** API, we don't need implement our own version of OpenCV/Numpy conversion anymore. For example, the following code works just right:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> lenna = cv2.imread('lenna.tiff', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
>>> lenna
array([[162, 162, 162, ..., 170, 155, 128],
       [162, 162, 162, ..., 170, 155, 128],
       [162, 162, 162, ..., 170, 155, 128],
       ..., 
       [ 43,  43,  50, ..., 104, 100,  98],
       [ 44,  44,  55, ..., 104, 105, 108],
       [ 44,  44,  55, ..., 104, 105, 108]], dtype=uint8)
>>> plt.imshow(lenna, cmap='gray')
>>> plt.show()
```

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but how can I determine the version of OpenCV I'm using? All I see is a `.__version__` option, but it only tells me the revision.

Comment: @Magsol, recent versions of OpenCV present both interfaces. You can use "import cv" and "import cv2". Try "import cv2" and see what you get. Also use your package management system to find the OpenCV version you have in your system. Or compile from the sources (see http://goo.gl/8ds4i ).

Comment: The OpenCV Sphinx-base documentation shows both interfaces, but the cv interface is considered "legacy". http://opencv.itseez.com/

Comment: I installed the `python-opencv` package through Ubuntu's package manager; in ipython, it doesn't recognize an `import cv2` statement. I tried re-installing the package, but it claims I already have the latest version installed.

Comment: In Ubuntu 11.04, the binary packages correspond to OpenCV 2.1. It's a pretty old version and consider the fact the cv API is legacy now. That's why I compile OpenCV from the sources. If you will work a lot with OpenCV + Numpy + Matplotlib, consider spend one hour or less compiling the sources and using the cv2 API. Life will be easier ;)

Comment: It took me awhile, but I managed to compile all four (NumPy, SciPy, Matplotlib, and OpenCV 2.3) from source. OpenCV seems to include both "cv" and "cv2", but the latter is missing some methods, most notably (which I use a lot) `calcOpticalFlowLK`. Is the "cv" implementation the same as 2.1? If so, would it be possible to do `cv2.imread()` and use that value in `cv.calcOpticalFlowLK()`, aka are the arrays between them interchangeable? I would test this myself but I got it working on a dev VM I set up for this purpose :P

Comment: According to the documentation, the function `calcOpticalFlowLK` is obsolete. To track sparse  features, use `cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()`. To track all the pixels, use `cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback()`. Note cv2 is **not** missing methods, but replacing the obsolete ones by the new implementations.